# .htaccess file sub-folder redirect

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, hosting

I know this has been posted in other places, but I have not been able to make it work properly. I am just trying to get a simple redirect from my root / to /html folder and add a .html extension so the url isn’t [www.websites.com/html/file.html](http://www.websites.com/html/file.html) but rather [www.website.com/file](http://www.website.com/file). Does anyone have any idea how to do this type of rewrite?

This is about all I have working properly.

```
RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)#$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>

RewriteBase /html/
```

Comment: Please post your attempt of implementing the required rewriting rule and explain its behavior and where that differs from what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond /html%{REQUEST_URI}.html -f
RequestRule ^ /html%{REQUEST_URI}.html [END]
```

For this to work the rewriting module needs to be loaded into the http server. Best is to implement such rules in the actual host configuration of the http server. If you do not have access to that (cheap hosting provider), then you can use a distributed configuration file (".htaccess"), but that needs to be enabled too.